# Are conflicts possible when writing multiple separate files using foreach R parallel?

Tags: r, shell, parallel-processing, io, multiple-instances

Since I cannot provide a reproducible example I will give you a description.
I need to process some thousand images with an image editing software (i.e. Rawtherapee).
In essence, I am using `foreach` in R to parallelize the use of Rawtherapee so that each worker generated by R will use command-line version of Rawtherapee by callying `shell`.
The steps are as follow:

1. I created a list with N elements in which I stored the file paths of the images. N is the number of cores I will use. The name of each file is modified by adding a tag which allows to assign it to a specific iteration of `foreach`.
2. each worker generated by `foreach` receive the chunk of the list of files that correspond to its number. And it creates the command to be passed to rawtherapee-cli
3. the worker call `shell` and start processing with rawtherapee-cli: the image is read, modified and then saved.

To give you an idea, my call to `foreach` is like this:

```
nc = cpus
cl = makeCluster(nc, type = "PSOCK") 
cl
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i= seq_along(set_split), .combine='c',
                .inorder=FALSE, .errorhandling='remove') %dopar% {
                 
script to generate the command for the cli
shell(cmd_string, intern=F,wait=T)

}
```

I'm on a Windows 10 machine and `shell` will call `cmd` by default (as far as I understand).

As you can understand, all the workers will have to write multiple files (i.e., each image they process), separately, on the hard drive.

My code works apparently fine. However I just realized that, at the end of the job, I was missing some images.
The number of missing files were more or less similar in each chunk, and in different positions in the sequence of paths, with no apparent pattern.

I inspected and tested my code thoroughly and I can't see a bug.

My question is:
is it possible that if 2 workers try to write their own file at the same time - or almost - they have some sort of conflict that prevent one of the 2 to be written (although it is not the same file name)?

If yes, how can this problem be addressed?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with multiple processes writing to different files simultaneously, that'd be a significant problem with the OS itself. If all R is doing for you is multi-proc coordination, I'd think it'd be much faster to use your non-R shell command directly via `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -P 20 yourscript.sh` or similar (20 here is the number of parallel processes ... your number of cores, likely). (If you don't know how to use `find` or `xargs`, that is easy to work through.

Comment: I should say that both `find` and `xargs` are provided in Rtools on windows, and native to linux/macos.

Comment: As an example, I just tested on some files, where my `yourscript.sh` takes a single argument, the filename, and prints out the PID and the filename (as proof that each filename gets their own dedicated script running). With that, I did `find path/to/dir -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -P 4 yourscript.sh`, and it ran individually on each file. See help pages for [`find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and [`xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) for info on their command-line arguments.

Comment: To quickly troubleshoot your original code parallel file writes, you could run it without Rawtherapee, giving a `cmd_string = "echo ' ' > file_name"`.